# Combining values in a Notes/Domino column that is categorized

Tags: lotus-notes, calculated-columns, notesview

I have a notes view that shows hundreds of peoples’ ages. I then created a categorized view so I can see how many people are in each age.  This works fine.

Problem is, I want to group these ages into five year brackets (I.e. age 0 to 5, 6 to 10,11 to 15,etc)
The field is called ‘age’ and it is a text field.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, brute-force way is to create a formula for your column that is categorized.

```
@If(Age <= 5; "0 to 5";
      Age > 5 & Age <= 10; "6 to 10";
      Age > 10 & Age <= 15; "11 to 15";
      ....
      Age > 100; "Over 100"; "Not specified");
```

Also, I believe you could create a hidden Age column before this one and sort by it to make the categories appear in age order

Comment: Age is a text field... So use NAge:= @TextToNumber(Age); and adapt the formula to use NAge.

Comment: Thank you @Ken Pespisa.  This looks like it will do the job.  Sorry, it took so long for me to get back to this site to see this.